# Datatables and Codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, datatables

I'm using the datatables plugin to format my tables with my data.

- I make the call to my model from my controller to gather all the data.
- I send the data array to the view file.
- I start a table tag in my view with the datatable class which calls the plugin to turn the regular html table into a datatables table.
- I check to verify that there is data in the array in the view and then if there is I do a foreach loop to create the table rows. If there is not data then I echo out a string of no data found.

My issue is when there is data it works fine however when there is not data I receive `Requested Unknown Parameter 1 from the data source for row 0` error message.

I've seen others that have come across this same issue before however all the other posts I have seen have explained that they have used the datatables json data while specifically working with the datatables plugin.

Any ideas on how to prevent this error message from displaying.

```
<table class="dynamicTable table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 1%;" class="uniformjs" id="checkboxth"><input type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th class="center">ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th class="center">Date</th>
            <th class="center" id="created_updated"></th>
            <th class="right" id="actions">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        //vardump($themes);
        if (isset($themes) && is_array($themes))
        {
            foreach ($themes AS $theme)
            {
                echo '<tr class="selectable">';
                echo '<td class="center uniformjs"><input type="checkbox" /></td>';
                echo '<td class="center">' . $theme->id . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $theme->name . '</td>';
                if ($theme->updated_at != '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
                {
                    echo '<td class="center" style="width: 80px;">' . date('d M Y', strtotime($theme->created_at)) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td class="center" style="width: 80px;"><span class="label label-block label-inverse">updated</span></td>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<td class="center" style="width: 80px;">' . date('d M Y', strtotime($theme->created_at)) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td class="center" style="width: 80px;"><span class="label label-block label-important">created</span></td>';
                }

                echo '<td class="center" style="width: 60px;">';
                echo '<a href="' . base_url() . 'themes/edit/' . $theme->id . '" class="btn-action glyphicons pencil btn-success"><i></i></a>';
                echo '<a href="' . base_url() . 'themes/delete/' . $theme->id . '" class="btn-action glyphicons remove_2 btn-danger"><i></i></a>';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td class="center" colspan="7">There are no themes.  Select Add a New Theme.</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the code that came with the theme.

```
/* DataTables */
if ($('.dynamicTable').size() > 0)
{
    $('.dynamicTable').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Post your code or we cannot help you!

Comment: Where is your datatables code? the one invoking the datatables api/fuctionality? that is giving you this error? Do you have a sample of the array you are working with? Is it an object or an array with objects?

Comment: Are you receiving this message in output or console?

Comment: @chris Its in my assets folder. I just didn't want to place too much code in the question and risk it not getting answered. My data is an array of objects. My error is displayed when there is no data to work with for the table.

Comment: Well.. when even I get this issue.. I find, that there is a column mix match.. usually in the case more columns defined than actually used...  but since your not posting your datatable specific API/function call that invokes the table its hard to be conclusive about that

Comment: but, you want an answer, so your posting as little code as you can (thats not specific to the problem, which will garuntee an answer almost always.... *sarcasm*))

Comment: I checked and the 7 in the colspan attribute should be 6 since there is 6 columns however I still receive the same error message.

Comment: We really need the dataTable initialization code to help, at the very least. The more code you post, the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: I posted the code above.

Comment: Do you receive the message only when there is no data in the `$themes` array or all the time?

Comment: Only when there's no data.

Comment: And you're sure that you changed `<td class="center" colspan="7">` to `<td class="center" colspan="6">`?

Comment: Yes. I did change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Please remove else condition from your code.Then your code will look like:

```
<table class="dynamicTable table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 1%;" class="uniformjs" id="checkboxth"><input type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th class="center">ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th class="center">Date</th>
            <th class="center" id="created_updated"></th>
            <th class="right" id="actions">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        //vardump($themes);
        if (isset($themes) && is_array($themes))
        {
            foreach ($themes AS $theme)
            {
                echo '<tr class="selectable">';
                echo '<td class="center uniformjs"><input type="checkbox" /></td>';
                echo '<td class="center">' . $theme->id . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $theme->name . '</td>';
                if ($theme->updated_at != '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
                {
                    echo '<td class="center" style="width: 80px;">' . date('d M Y', strtotime($theme->created_at)) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td class="center" style="width: 80px;"><span class="label label-block label-inverse">updated</span></td>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<td class="center" style="width: 80px;">' . date('d M Y', strtotime($theme->created_at)) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td class="center" style="width: 80px;"><span class="label label-block label-important">created</span></td>';
                }

                echo '<td class="center" style="width: 60px;">';
                echo '<a href="' . base_url() . 'themes/edit/' . $theme->id . '" class="btn-action glyphicons pencil btn-success"><i></i></a>';
                echo '<a href="' . base_url() . 'themes/delete/' . $theme->id . '" class="btn-action glyphicons remove_2 btn-danger"><i></i></a>';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            } 
        }
       /* else
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td class="center" colspan="7">There are no themes.  Select Add a New Theme.</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }*/
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it will works.Because datatable automatically handle no data in table.